# sharekit ios5 shows linker error with existing code

Tags: ios5, package, linker-errors, sharekit

I am working on sharekit in ios5.  I changed sharekit package from 3.2 to ios 5  but when I build it shows following error.

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SHKFacebook", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ProjectAppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SHKItem", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in XXXViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SHKActionSheet", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in XXXViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386.

Any suggestion are highly appreciated.

Thanks&Regards,
Sathish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem with the following linker error:

Undefined symbols for architecture i386: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SHK"

I resolved it by adding SHK.m to compiled sources under Project settings->Target->Build Phases. Not sure why SHK.m was not in the compiled sources list, and it was working previous to duplicating the Target. After the duplication I couldn't link for any of the targets.

Adding SHKFacebook.m or SHK.m to compiled sources might help you.